# Send Info from Installer - Custom page fields and logs

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to make an Inno Setup installer that is capable of sending some logs, and also a bug report text for which I made a custom page:

[image: image of custom page with various entry fields]

In the following code I'm trying to import a function that I found in [(MSDN) SmtpMail.Send Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b46af9f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), but without success:

```pascal
var
  ExtraPage : TInputQueryWizardPage;
  RichEditViewer: TRichEditViewer;
  labelchar,max_char:TLabel;
  Installer_bug,Content_bug: TNewRadioButton;

function SetFocus(hWnd: HWND): HWND;external 'SetFocus@user32.dll stdcall';
function GetSystemMetrics (nIndex: Integer): Integer;external 'GetSystemMetrics@User32.dll stdcall setuponly';
//function Send(message: MailMessage); external 'Send@System.Web.dll stdcall setuponly';

procedure isAt(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key ='@' then begin
    Key := #0;
    SetFocus(ExtraPage.Edits[4].Handle);
  end;
end;

procedure NumbersOnly(Sender:TObject; var Key: Char);
var s:string;
begin
  s := ('1234567890'#8);
  if pos(key,s) =0 then 
    Key:=#0;
end;

procedure OffsetPageItem(Page: TInputQueryWizardPage; Index, Offset: Integer);
begin
//Labels
  Page.PromptLabels[Index].SetBounds(10,Offset,55,30);

//Name field
  Page.Edits[Index].SetBounds(100,Offset,200,40);

//Resolution field
  if Index=1 then
    Page.Edits[Index].SetBounds(100,Offset,40,40);
    Page.Edits[Index].MaxLength:=4

//x field
  if Index=2 then begin
    Page.Edits[Index].SetBounds(160,Offset,40,40);
    Page.PromptLabels[Index].SetBounds(145,Offset+3,10,20);
    Page.Edits[Index].MaxLength:=4
  end;

//E-Mail field
  if Index=3 then begin
    Page.Edits[Index].SetBounds(100,Offset,130,40);
    if not (Pos('@',Page.Values[Index])=0) then
      Page.Edits[Index+1].SelectAll;
  end;

//@ field
  if Index=4 then begin
    Page.Edits[Index].SetBounds(250,Offset,70,40);
    Page.PromptLabels[Index].SetBounds(235,Offset+3,10,20);
  end;

//Description field
  if Index=5 then begin
    ExtraPage.PromptLabels[index].SetBounds(10,Offset+15,80,60);
    ExtraPage.Edits[Index].Hide;
    RichEditViewer := TRichEditViewer.Create(ExtraPage);
    RichEditViewer.ScrollBars:=ssVertical;
    with RichEditViewer do begin
      Parent:=ExtraPage.Surface;
      SetBounds(100,Offset+25,300,100);
      Text:='Having a bug? Write it here... ';
      MaxLength:=400;
    end;
  end;
end;


procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  index:Integer;

begin
  ExtraPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome, 'E-mail sender','Add The following information!','');
  ExtraPage.SubCaptionLabel.Hide;
  //index=0;
  index:=ExtraPage.Add('Name: ', False);
  ExtraPage.Values[index]:=ExpandConstant('{computername}');
  OffsetPageItem(ExtraPage,index,10);

  //index=1;
  index:=ExtraPage.Add('Resolution: ', False);
  OffsetPageItem(ExtraPage,index,40);
  ExtraPage.Values[index]:=IntToStr(GetSystemMetrics(0));
  ExtraPage.Edits[index].OnKeyPress:=@NumbersOnly;

  //index=2;
  index:=ExtraPage.Add(' x ', False);
  OffsetPageItem(ExtraPage,index,40);
  ExtraPage.Values[index]:=IntToStr(GetSystemMetrics(1));
  ExtraPage.Edits[index].OnKeyPress:=@NumbersOnly;

  //index=3;
  index:=ExtraPage.Add('E-mail: ', False);
  OffsetPageItem(ExtraPage,index,70);
  ExtraPage.Edits[index].OnKeyPress:=@isAt;

  //index=4;
  index:=ExtraPage.Add('@', False);
  OffsetPageItem(ExtraPage,index,70);
  ExtraPage.Edits[index].OnKeyPress:=@isAt;

  //index=5;
  index:=ExtraPage.Add('Short Description:'+#10+'(How to reproduce?)', False);
  OffsetPageItem(ExtraPage,index,100);

  labelchar:=TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with labelchar do begin
    Parent:=ExtraPage.Surface;
    SetBounds(10,200,100,30);
    Caption:='Max number of'+#10#13+'characters: ';
  end;
  max_char:=TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with max_char do begin
    Parent:=ExtraPage.Surface;
    Font.Style:=[fsBold];
    SetBounds(68,213,100,30);
    Caption:=IntToStr(400);
  end;

  Installer_bug:=TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm)
  with Installer_bug do begin
  Parent := ExtraPage.Surface;
  SetBounds(100,100,80,20);
  Caption:='Installer bug'
  end;

  Content_bug:=TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm)
  with Content_bug do begin
  Parent := ExtraPage.Surface;
  SetBounds(190,100,80,20);
  Caption:='Content bug'
  end;

end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  line:String;
//  E_mail :MailMessage;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = ExtraPage.ID then begin
    line:=ExtraPage.PromptLabels[0].Caption + ExtraPage.Values[0] + #10;
    line:=line + ExtraPage.PromptLabels[1].Caption + ExtraPage.Values[1] + ExtraPage.PromptLabels[2].Caption+ExtraPage.Values[2] + #10;
    line:=line + ExtraPage.PromptLabels[3].Caption + ExtraPage.Values[3] + ExtraPage.PromptLabels[4].Caption+ExtraPage.Values[4] + #10;
    line:=line +'Type: ';
    if Installer_bug.Checked then
      line:=line + Installer_bug.Caption + #10;
    if Content_bug.Checked then
      line:=line + Content_bug.Caption + #10;
    line:=line + ExtraPage.PromptLabels[5].Caption + #10#13;
    line:=line + RichEditViewer.Text;

    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{src}\test.txt'),line,false);

//    E_mail:=MailMessage.Create(WizardForm);
//    E_mail.From= "test@sdsd.com"
//    E_mail.To = "test@gmail.com"
//    E_mail.Subject="test";
//    SmtpMail.SmtpServer= "MyMailServer";
//    SmtpMail.Send(E_mail);

  end;
end;
```

Comment: i've also found this [site](http://delphi.about.com/od/indy/a/email-send-indy.htm) ...

Comment: still no one have answered :(, is it something that i did wrong in my post? am i asking something i should not ? Usually by now i would've get at least some hints... or a "is not possible" comment :D

Comment: You should reduce the code to the absolute minimum necessary to reproduce the problem, and explain what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: Without an external library or e-mail client capable of MAPI installed on the user's machine (like Outlook, Thunderbird etc.), you're certainly out of luck. There is also one big issue when dealing with e-mail reporting; for that, you must have an e-mail account. Either your own, thrown with its credentials to the public, or the user's own, where the user would have to provide the account information into your setup when using an external library, or being logged in on their e-mail client. I would prefer HTTP way. You'd have a reporting server where would your setup POST the reports...

Comment: @TLama I see , i will look into the HTTP thingy , maybe i'm successful that way , i can find a host for keeping the logs :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue this is what I did...

bmail:

```
bmail -s smtp.example.net -t you@example.com -f me@example.net -h ^
  -a "mail subject" -b "message text"
```

You could also write your own mailer to execute.

```
[Run]
begin
// need to email Version
//  blat -to %eMail% -f %eMail% %subj% %server% %debug% %x%
  ExtractTemporaryFile('blat.exe');
  connExe:=ExpandConstant('{tmp}')+'\blat.exe';
  connTxt := ' -to ' + E_mail.From.text + ' -f '+ E_mail.To.Text + E_mail.Subject.Text + 'SmtpMail.SmtpServer.text' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}\log.log');
  Log('The Value is connTxt: ' + connTxt );
  if Exec(connExe, connTxt, '' , SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
     //MsgBox(IntToStr(ResultCode), mbError, mb_Ok);
    connTxt := ' -to ' + E_mail.From.text + ' -f '+ E_mail.To.Text + E_mail.Subject.Text + 'SmtpMail.SmtpServer.text' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}\log.log');
     ExpandConstant('{tmp}\log.log');
     Log('The Value is connTxt: ' + connTxt );
     if Exec(connExe, connTxt, '' , SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
      begin
        MsgBox( 'The '+ E_mail.Subject.Text + ' Email has been sent' , mbInformation, mb_Ok);
        result := True;
       end;
    end;
end;
```

warning the names where change to address the question and has not been fully test as is. 
@TLama is right but why not use the application to send the debug messages?